# Upload Image from Android app to Server after login

Tags: php, android, sqlite

Hi i'm newbie to android development... in the demo that i'm following for login and registration it shows that if user logs in then data is fetched from server's database and stored in sqlite.

For registration, once the user is done with the registration, the details are stored in server db and also in sqlite. Well,  i am not so clear with this idea and now am about to move to next Activity where i need to upload images for the current user. So, do i have to use sqlite even for dis or directly fetching from server is enough?

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html/1

Thanks

Comment: DO you mean user will upload image to server by your android app?

Comment: yes i want upload image from my android app to server

Comment: You can try uploading the images to the server by creating a new directory on the server based on the username. So, every time the user uploads any image, it uploads directly to the directory of the user.

Comment: so no need to include image details in android sqlite ?

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to save the details of the image uploaded by the user locally in the db, then you can do it. Either store it as BLOB or just image name. However, it's unnecessary to store it locally in sqlite. You can instead store the details on the server like "path" to the image file.

Comment: okay... why do v store user info in sqlite?